# Estoy haciendo una funcion que devuelva los documentos de mi DB (firebase), pero al momento de llamarla, devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase

Esta es la funcion que estoy implementando para recibir los Docs, como dice la documentacion de Firebase:

```
export const getItemsForCollectionForTable = async (collectionForDB) => {
const products = [];
var unsubscribe;
try {
const q = query(collection(db, collectionForDB));
unsubscribe = await onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let data = doc.data();
    products.push(data);
    data;
  });
});
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
//return unsubscribe;
return products;
};
```

Al retornar el unsubscribe, recibo esto en consola: `()=>{s.La(),e.asyncQueue.enqueueAndForget((async()=>__PRIVATE_eventManagerUnlisten(await __PRIVATE_getEventManager(e),o)))}`, y cuando retorno el array, si me da los documentos de mi DB, pero para tratarlos en la otra funcion que pongo a continuación de ejemplo, no me da la posibilidad de tratar a cada docoumento (en otras palabras, no puedo recorrer el arreglo)

```
const aa = async () => {                                                                    
let a = await getItemsForCollectionForTable("products");                        
console.log(a);                                                                              
};                                                                                        
aa();
```

Comment: Tu función no retorna valor alguno, y cuando no se retorna algo, javascript retorna `undefined`

Comment: Lo escribí tal cual como en la documentacion de Firebase, solo cuando le doy console.log dentro de la funcion para retornar los docs, ahí si retorna todo

Comment: Te insisto no estas retornando valor alguno. El `forEach` no entiendo para que lo usas, pero por probar algo cambia `const unsubscribe = await onSnapshot....` por `return await onSnapshot...`

Comment: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?hl=es-419#web-modular-api_4) en la documentacion de Firebase, sugiere trabajar con forEach, ya que estoy pidiendo los datos en tiempo real con **onSnapShot** .. Y no funciona bro:(, ya intenté lo que tu dices y sale lo siguiente en consola: `()=>{s.La(),e.asyncQueue.enqueueAndForget((async()=>__PRIVATE_eventManagerUnlisten(await __PRIVATE_getEventManager(e),o)))}`

Comment: "En la documentación sugiere trabajar con forEach" -> Si, porque en el ejemplo recorren la colección para imprimir cosas... si lo que quieres es devolver el producto de la primera colección no tiene sentido ninguno ese forEach. La documentación está para entenderla... no para copiar y pegar sin pensar. Coincido con el compañero Yussef, tu función no devuelve nada... necesitas tener un `return` en algún lado para que tu función devuelva algo! Y no dentro del forEach, forEach no debería llevar un return dentro, en vez de forEach usa un map, o directamente coge el primer elemento y listo.

Comment: Utilizo forEach para imprimir todos los documentos que tengo en mi colección llamada ``products`, y tenías razón por lo de devolver algo, ahora lo guardo en una array y devuelvo esa array, y ahí si me funciona,